# Set Header colour and border for all sheets in an excel file with python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have an Excel file with multiple sheets. I am trying to set the header's background color and border for all the Excel sheets at once.

These excel sheets are output dataframes which I am creating through `ExcelWriter`.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(path, 'file.xlsx'), engine = 'xlsxwriter'
df1.to_excel(writer, sheetname = 'df1', index = False)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheetname = 'df2', index = False)
.
.
.
.
and so on
```

I'm just trying to figure out how to add the formatting in these sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`add_format`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html?highlight=add_format#add_format) along with [`write`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html?highlight=write#write) :

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

dmap = {"bg_color": "#00D100", "border": 2, "bold": True}

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"C": [7, 8], "D": [9, 10], "E": [11, 12]})

list_dfs = [df1, df2]

with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    for idx1, df in enumerate(list_dfs, start=1):
        ws_name = f"Sheet{idx1}" # change the sheet name here (df for example)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=ws_name, index=False)
        for idx2, col in enumerate(df.columns):
            writer.sheets[ws_name].write(0, idx2, col, writer.book.add_format(dmap))
```

Output :

[image]

[image]